# Django: Variable in template doesn't display

Tags: django

```
views.py
def tick(request):
   leave_id=request.POST['leave_id']
   ticked_leave=leave.objects.filter(id=leave_id).select_related('employee')
   emp_name=ticked_leave[0].employee.emp_name;
   data=dict()
   data['ticked_leave'] = render_to_string('m_manage/tick_modal.html', {
        'emp_name':emp_name,'leave_id':leave_id
    })
   return JsonResponse(data)
```

In my template I am using:

```
  <h4 class="modal-title" >Do You want to accept <b>{{emp_name}}</b> leave?</h4>
```

It display nothing..It just displays Do you want to accept leave? leaving emp_name...
Thanks in advance....

Comment: Can you put the data contains? also, if you did that query to get emp_name by django shell Do you get any info?

Comment: In shell when I wrote the query I got the output of the employee name.But I need to pass the value of variable through JsonResponse...I am unable to pass value through render to string ??